# How to pass variables into $rootScope from backend

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rootscope

I need to pass some variables from backend to Angular frontend in HTML code. Ideally, I like to have it within `$rootScope`. However, `$rootScope` is not defined yet when the page is loaded. The only way I can do it is:

`var myVar = ["aa", "bb"];`

Then get it from `$window.myVar`

So is there a way to **wait** until `$rootScope` is defined by Angular and then parse value into it within HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a constant and injecting it where you need it?

`angular.module('yourModule').constant('yourVar', ['aa', 'bb']);`

Then you can use it in the run stage:

```
angular.module('yourModule').run(function($rootScope, yourVar) {
    $rootScope.yourVar = yourVar;
});
```

Comment: But this still assume `yourVar` is in global scope when the HTML is parsed right?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, try something like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', []);

myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.myVar = ['aa', 'bb'];
});

// we launch Angular manually when DOM is ready
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
});
```

Comment: I already had `var myApp = angular.module('App', []);` defined in app.js. Would this work?